# Unable to create ~/.gnome2 directory: Permission denied-Warning with Cron PHP and phpseclib

Tags: php, cron, phpseclib

I running a PHP script with cron that uses phpseclib installed via composer (version 0.3.9). I'm using Net_SFTP to check an sFTP server for new files. Everything is working fine, but the script is generating this warning:

```
(process:16615): libgnomevfs-WARNING **: Unable to create ~/.gnome2 directory: Permission denied
```

The script is run by the apache user. The warning will show up even without doing a login. Just instantiating the Net_SFTP class will trigger this, and I only see it when ran from the cron job. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$host = 'my.sftp.server';
$test = new Net_SFTP($host);
```

The cron for apache is configured like this:

```
MAILTO=myEmail@example.com
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/sftpCheck.php
```

The error appears from the stderr output when the cron script runs.
Any ideas what this warning is and how I can correct it?

Comment: I would just create the folder yourself, change the permissions and then see what happens

Comment: @NicholasYoung The apache user didn't have a directory under the /home/ directory. I created one as well as a /.gnome2 directory inside. I changed permissions to both folders to apache, still no changes.

Comment: What does `$sftp->pwd()` say when you first log in? And what are the permissions / who is the owner of that directory? Creating `/home/apache` isn't going to do any good the default directory that the SFTP server puts the user in question is in the `/etc/` directory (as an example).

Comment: @neubert Thanks for your response. $sftp->pwd() says "/". Do you think it's trying to create the ~/.gnome2 directory on the sftp server and not on the client server?

Comment: @khartnett - it's hard to say since you haven't posted any code. phpseclib, itself, doesn't generate any E_USER_WARNING messages that look like that, but then again, I don't think PHP does either. Are you trying to create the directory on the sftp server or on the client server?

Comment: Hi @neubert. The warning will trigger even before logging into the sftp server. Just instantiating the class will get this warning to show up. Code has been added to the answer above. I'm also not entirely sure this is a PHP warning, or something on the system level.

Comment: Wow - that alone will trigger the error? That kinda makes me if you'd get the error even if you commented out the `$test = new Net_SFTP($host);`.

Comment: Hi @neubert. I commented out that line to test and the warning disappears, so it's got to be something in the Net_SFTP constructor

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you running? The latest is v0.3.9. If you are running the latest version lmk and I can give you modifications to do that'll assist in diagnosing the problem (or you could give me SFTP access to the server if you'd be so inclined). If you aren't running the latest version then upgrade and try again.

Comment: Hi @neubert, I was running 0.3.6. I thought I updated to 0.3.9 but I guess I didn't run composer update. After updating the warning still shows up, but this time it only shows up if/when the login method is called. I'm currently modifying that section to pinpoint where this warning is occurring. Sorry I'm not able to share the ftp

Comment: My guess: it's probably the fsockopen() call that's causing that error. That call used to be in the constructor but was later moved to the login() method. Try out `<?php fsockopen($host, 22); ?>` and see what happens.

Comment: It gets past fsockopen, it looks like it's somewhere in _key_exchange() of SSH2

Comment: It's definitely caused by @phpinfo(); which is called in BigInteger.php